# Unable to grant access to VisualStudio.com GIT Repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure account, linked to a VisualStudio.com git repository.

I have added two new users in the Azure Active Directory, and gave them at first developper role, and then global administrator as it was not working.

Then, in VisualStudio.com, I gave them the admin role on the project level.

And also tried Basic, Stakeholder and Visual Studio subscriber access level in the Organization settings.

Each time, we disconnected and reconnected to the project web page (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_Git/yyy)

None of these allowed them to see the git repository.

How the hell should we configure this gaz factory to get access to the code repo?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it that the new users can login the azure devops project, but cannot see the Repos section?  I tested a user with basic access level and being added as project admin or contributor. He can access the repositories without problem. Are you sure they are added as Basic user rather thanStakeholder?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT, yes they are basic. It turns out the user I have tested with got somehow corrupted when I removed it from Azure AD and re-added it again later. Looking in visualstudio, it gets displayed with a line below showing OIDCONFLICT. So I tried with another user and it worked when adding the user to the team as well in the project settings. The first user ended up corrupted.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Seems like a genuine problem. We have seen something similar with a user with OIDCONFLICT. Upvoting - maybe some other of the 500+ readers will upvote also, and the problem can be fixed by MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user was removed from Azure Active Directory and then added again. This completely screwed it up. You can see it in the Visual Studio project settings as it shows OIDCONFLICT below the mail address.

In addition, there's a second trick: add the user to the team as well in the project settings.
Whole flow that worked for me is as follow:

- Add the user as guest (for me email address was outside my organization), in Active Directory of my portal.azure.com.
- Go to yourproject.visualstudio.com, display the organization page (clic on left part of the breadcrumb at the top if you are already in the project view (where we see wiki, GIT etc on th left)).
- So in the organization page, go to setting at bottom left and add the user to your organization at Basic level (not stakeholder ar it cannot access git repo this way) and assign him the project.
- Now, navigate to the Project inside visualstudio.com, in Project settings (bottom left). Select Team and add the user to your team. Next, go to Repos/Repositories and check or add necessary rights there.
- Make sure your user logs out from the browser and clears its cookies before logging in again.

I mean if one guy from Microsoft reads it, please provide a whole tutorial and not only docs with parts of necessary information. I lost a day on this.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this issue, the fix for me is usually removing remnants of the user from the deleted users blade in AAD.  Next I check permissions under organization settings and remove those stale entries from their project association.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This ended up being the solution for me - a user was initially added via admin.microsoft.com, then removed, then a new user with the same email was added. The initial user was then removed from Deleted Users in AAD, however permissions that had been created in Azure Devops were not removed - this resulted in a ghost user being available in user dropdowns